# mysqldump devuelve una consulta vacia cuando no hay conexion con la base de datos

Tags: mysql

quiero hacer una copia de seguridad programada con mysqldump. Para ello utilizo un archivo .bat que se ejecuta periodicamente. Pero el problema que tengo es que cuando no hay conexion con la base de datos me devuelve una copia vacia y me la sobreescribe a la que ya tenia del dia anterior. Lo que pretendo es que cuando no consiga conectarse a la base de datos (si el servidor esta caido por lo que sea) no realice la accion de respaldo. ¿como puedo lograr esto?, este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
mysqldump -hsql172.main-hosting.eu -uu117490907_ferreteria -pmiPassword u117490907_ferreteria > copiaseguridad.sql
```

Comment: ¿No te convendría crear un archivo diferente para cada día? Por ejemplo con la fecha en AAAAMMDD: `> copiaseguridad%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%.sql`

Comment: ya lo hice asi al principio, pero me llena la carpeta de archivos (en un año 365 archivos), queria que cuando no haya conexion no haga el backup, si eso es posible, gracias.

Comment: Podrías tener un procesos programado diferente que te mantenga sólo los últimos N archivos.

Comment: Prueba redireccionando el error, agrega al final: `2> nul`

Answer (score 0):

Pues la cosa está en la forma como le envías la salida del comando al archivo. No depende de `mysqldump` y el output se abre antes de que mysqldump pueda decir nada. `>` se usa explícitamente para reemplazar, así que él comienza por crear de nuevo el apuntador, escucha atento y, cuando mysqldump termina con status 2 (Exception), cierra y guarda.

El camino fácil es crear un archivo diferente cada día y programar una limpieza semanal que deje sólo los últimos 7, algo por el estilo.

Comment: a ver especifico un poco mas. Se trata de un archivo .bat asi que se trataria de programar el archivo .bat. Si se pudiese hacer un `if (no hay conexion)` se podria solucionar.

Comment: ¿y como hago el .bat que borre los archivos con fecha de creacion mayor de siete dias?